# adding tuple elements in a list

Tags: python, list, tuples

```
l1=[(2,1),(3,2),(4,5)]
l2=[(2,3),(3,6),(11,3)]
```

I need:

```
result=[(2,4),(3,8),(4,5),(11,3)]
```

using for loop I was able to add tuples having the same first element.

```
>>> result = []
l1 = [(2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 5)]
l2 = [(2, 3), (3, 6), (11, 3)]
for x, y in l1:
    for p, q in l2:
        if x == p:
            result.append((x, (y + q)))

>>> result
[(2, 4), (3, 8)]
```

How do I further add `(4,5),(11,3)`

Comment: The elements that you add the second value of; do they have to have the same indices? I mean, what does `l1=[(2,1),(3,2),(4,5)]` and `l2=[(3,6),(2,3),(11,3)]` output?

Comment: yes when the indices(e.g:  2) are same, the second elements of tuple from different lists must be added    `(2,1),(2,3)===(2,4)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So many ways to achieve the same goal... I like it!

Here is my solution.

```
l1=[(2,1),(3,2),(4,5)]
l2=[(2,3),(3,6),(11,3)]

d1 = dict(l1)
d2 = dict(l2)
result = []

for k in d1:
    if k in d2:
        result.append((k,d1[k]+d2[k]))
    else:
        result.append((k,d1[k]))

for k in d2:
    if k not in d1:
        result.append((k,d2[k]))


>>>print result
[(2, 4), (3, 8), (4, 5), (11, 3)]
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be easily done by using dict formed with `l1` and iterating over `l2`, see working code snippet below:

```
l1=[(2,1),(3,2),(4,5)]
l2=[(2,3),(3,6),(11,3)]
result = dict(l1)

for y in l2:
    result[y[0]] = result.get(y[0],0) + y[1]

result = result.items()
print result #[(11, 3), (2, 4), (3, 8), (4, 5)]
```

Or simply build results by iterating over concatenation of `l1` and `l2`:

```
l1=[(2,1),(3,2),(4,5)]
l2=[(2,3),(3,6),(11,3)]
result = {}
for item in l1 + l2:
    result[item[0]] = result.get(item[0],0) + item[1]
```

**Good luck!**

Comment: how and where do you learn this stuff?I am learning python by myself.They do not teach us in school(undergrad).I see some online courses but they are all basic level.How should I train to be an expert like the people answering questions instantaneously on stack overflow?Thankyou

Comment: @zaolee_dragon Stackoverflow is an excellent source of info, tips and tricks, you should definitely participate to improve your learning. Also, coursera.com offers some exquisite and free to follow python classes. I strongly suggest you  this one https://www.coursera.org/learn/interactive-python-1

Comment: @zaolee_dragon official python tutorials is great place to start learning python https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to go through the elements of `l2` for all elements of `l1` if I understand what you're going for. Just use [**`zip`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) (or **[`izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest)** if the lists have an uneven size) to use a tuple from each list and then `append` the first item and the sum if the first item matches and `extend` both tuples if they don't:

```
for tup1, tup2 in zip(l1, l2):
    if tup1[0] == tup2[0]:
        result.append((tup1[0], (tup1[1] + tup2[1])))
    else:
        result.extend([tup1, tup2])
```

With your input, this returns the required output:

```
>>> result
... [(2, 4), (3, 8), (4, 5), (11, 3)]
```

Comment: l1=[(2,1),(3,1),(5,1),(7,2)],

 l2=[(3,1)]
Didn't work for this.

Comment: What should the result be then? You can always use `zip_longest` to iterate with `lists` of different sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Seems natural to use a dictionary to keep track of which keys are already used. You can reduce the code size by using `defaultdict`:

```
import collections

l1=[(2,1),(3,2),(4,5)]
l2=[(2,3),(3,6),(11,3)]

d = collections.defaultdict(int)
for x,y in l1 + l2:
    d[x] += y
print sorted(d.items())
```